# Run aiohttp alongside another event loop in the same code

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram, aiohttp, telethon

I have a bot that runs Telethon and aiohttp.server in the same code, working at the same time

This is a simplified example of how i ran it in aiohttp version 3.7.4.post0

```
from aiohttp import web
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id="1234567"
api_hash="1234567890adcbefgh"
bot_token="1234567:abcdefgh0987654321"

bot=TelegramClient("my",api_id,api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

# Simple TG handler
async def tg_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)
    await event.reply("HEY")

# Simple GET handler at /
async def http_handler_main(request):
    return web.Response(body="Hi",content_type="text/plain",charset="utf-8",status=200)

async def build_app():
    app=web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get("/",http_handler_main)])
    return app

bot.add_event_handler(tg_handler,events.NewMessage())
web.run_app(build_app(),port="80")
```

Since I updated to 3.8.1 this no longer works correctly
I am using python 3.9.6 btw and Telethon version is still is the same as before this happened

EDIT1:
EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:
Run the webserver and the telegram bot

Comment: What does “no longer works correctly” mean? Please edit the question to include more details. If you’re seeing an exception, please include it along with any traceback you see.

Comment: @dirn the expected behavior for this is to run the webserver with the Telethon bot code

Comment: In version 3.8.1 it's only running the webserver. In the previous version of aiohttp that i was using (3.7.4.post0) it ran both. My bot is running with the old version, i'm trying to get it to work with the new version

Answer (score 0):

`web.run_app` creates a new `asyncio` event loop. Telethon by default uses the "current" `asyncio` event loop (which is the default for the main thread in this case). Because they're different even loops, they can't possibly work together.

Either create the `TelegramClient` inside `async def build_app()` (so it picks up the right event loop), or use `web.run_app(..., loop=client.loop)`.

If `web.run_app` does not support setting the loop, you will need to do [whatever it's doing](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/eb6b8636bb0fb1a3164e7f4aa6d55cae6309f822/aiohttp/web.py#L464) manually with `client.loop` instead.

Comment: I'll try it out. I'll stick to that old version of aiohttp in case i don't figure it out anyways